# R What is the use of the function registerDoParallel in multi-core computing

Tags: r, parallel-processing

In the following code, I could got result in a very short time:

```
library(doParallel)
sepnum = 8
cl <- makeCluster(sepnum)
#registerDoParallel(cl, cores=sepnum)
temp = foreach(i=1:sepnum, .combine='rbind') %dopar% 
  {temp = data.frame(1,2,3)}
stopCluster(cl)
```

I commented `registerDoParallel(cl, cores=sepnum)` out because even without this line, the code still work properly, but I saw many people's code example has used registerDoParallel in their code.

So what did that function do? if I remove that line, what could be the essential problem

Comment: You need to use `registerDoParallel(cl)`, otherwise the foreach loop won't be parallelize.

Comment: Yes, and register with already named clusters would made it be closed easily

Comment: It's either (a) `registerDoParallel(cl)` with `cl <- makeCluster(nworkers)` or (b) `registerDoParallel(cores=nworkers)`, but never `registerDoParallel(cl, cores=sepnum)`.  Also, note that (a) produces a so-called PSOCK cluster or background R sessions, whereas on Linux & macOS, (b) used forked R workers similar to `parallel::mclapply()`.  It's only on Windows, where (b) == (a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is essential. Try closing and re-opening RStudio to see that if you do not run `registerDoParallel()` then you will receive the error message

```
Warning message:
executing %dopar% sequentially: no parallel backend registered
```

See more info [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf#page=2)